# There is some name to describe databases that are about domains like movies, games, etc?

Tags: database, terminology

This is question is only about terminology.

I want to know if there is some special name to describe the database that are about some theme/domains like movies, games, music, places, etc.

Comment: Don't really understand what you are asking. But maybe you want to know what technology they use? MySQL is pretty popular as well as others like MongoDB

Comment: @theDazzler The question is about terminology. I want to know if there is another name to call database like specific themes described in the question or is simply "database".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally just "X database". For example, "movie database", "game database", and so on.

In some contexts you can refer to what is essentially a database by some other names, for example in Prolog you talk about the "knowledge base".

There are some words in the English language that basically describe databases, such as dictionaries, atlases, and encyclopedias, but those are generally considered things and are implemented with databases.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think there is a name, but searching a lot, I found not. You're right, it's simply "name" database.